# Using javascript, how to make xhr request to get json of what is in my mongo collection?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, reactjs

I'm trying to make a GET using javascript only (not jQuery, as I am using React) and I'm wondering how to get only the JSON back.  Can someone please help?  Basically, if I use the postman app and do GET at `localhost:3000/api/v1/posts`, I am seeing all the posts I have created.

If I can get this into an object, then I can use that later with `Object.keys()`.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        console.log("success : " + request.responseText);
        var mPosts = JSON.parse(request)
    } else {
        //This would print if something goes wrong along with the error message
        console.log("other status : " + request.status + " : " + request.responseText);
    }
};

request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
//need to serialize payload before sending it
request.send();
```

Comment: you parse `responseText` not `request`. `request` is the xhr instance object, `responseText` as the name implies is the text returned in the response.

Comment: Also just so you know, it's perfectly ok to use jQuery and React together, especially if you are using jQuery just to simply life by using things like `$.ajax`. Just stay away from direct DOM manipulation. You can even get jQuery via npm :)

Comment: if you want your xhr request to work across browsers, you should be using $jquery with your react.

Comment: o ok.  how can I use jquery only ajax portion?  what is superagent can it be used?

Comment: Yes superagent is perfectly fine. If you're only going to use ajax, you don't need all of jquery

Comment: thank you.  I have just finished the superagent.  it is super easy to use!!  very nice.